# How do I sort a linked list of structures by one of the fields?

Tags: c, file-io, structure

Wow now i know I dont. Lol.

I've got my structure like this:

```
struct Medico{ 
int Id_Doctor;
int Estado;
char Nombre[60]; ////focus on this part of the structure, this is name.
char Clave_Acceso[20];
char Especialidad[40];
struct Medico *next;
};
```

And I want to organize the structure depending on the name(alphabetical order..) any ideas on how to tackle this problem?

for example

```
Albert Haynesworth
Bob Marley
Carl Johnson
```

Thank you very much in advanced. :)(C, Unix)

Comment: It seems more like you have an array of these structures that you want ordered? Why not create a sort method that takes in an array of Medico items and sorts them on Medico->Nombre

Comment: What are you asking? How to compare two strings? How to sort? How to move elements in a linked list?

Comment: @Nathan
I've got plenty users on the structure and I want to display them by alphabetical order of the name; Im asking for some help on how to do it.

Comment: @Ro: Are you only trying to *display* them that way, or are you also trying to keep them internally represented that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing a mergesort over a linked list in C is quite easy:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    struct node *next;
    char *data;
};

struct node *
divlist (struct node *n) {
    int i = 0;
    if (n) {
        struct node *tail, *n2 = n;
        while (1) {
            n2 = n2->next;
            if (!n2) break;
            if (i++ & 1) n = n->next;
        }
        tail = n->next;
        n->next = NULL;
        return tail;
    }
    return NULL;
}

struct node *
mergelists(struct node *a, struct node *b) {
    struct node *n;
    struct node **last = &n;
    if (!a) return b;
    if (!b) return a;

    while (1) {
        if (strcmp(a->data, b->data) > 1) {
            *last = b;
            last = &b->next;
            b = b->next;
            if (!b) {
                *last = a;
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            *last = a;
            last = &a->next;
            a = a->next;
            if (!a) {
                *last = b;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return n;
}

struct node *
sortlist (struct node *n) {
    struct node *tail = divlist(n);
    if (!tail) return n;
    return mergelists(sortlist(n), sortlist(tail));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    struct node *n1, *n = NULL;
    for (i = argc; --i >= 1;) {
        n1 = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(*n1));
        n1->data = argv[i];
        n1->next = n;
        n = n1;
    }

    n1 = n = sortlist(n);

    while (n1) {
        printf("%s\n", n1->data);
        n1 = n1->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you will have to modify this code to use your data structure and the right comparison!

Answer (score 1):

C can't sort for you, nor maintain a sorted data structure. As others have suggested, you need to sort it yourself. I would do this when you create a new Medico, since inserting into a linked list is easy, and you can just find where it belongs as you iterate.

If Medico's order needs to be different, than you will need to sort the list whenever you display it. You'll probably want to iterate to pull out every name, then sort the resultant array using any of a number of techniques (depending on the size).

Assuming the list order is otherwise of no concern, keep it in order.

Comment: the list is already in a certain order, as it is listed according to  the id of the user(Id_Doctor);

Comment: Then as has been noted below, you'll need to copy the names out of the id_doctor-sorted list into an array, and sort that. There's some code below to both copy the names out and sort the array. zoul's code should work fine for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to look at implementations of either [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Simple_version) or [mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergesort). I believe that the c std lib qsort implementation takes an array and not a linked list, so you may need to implement your own (although I'm pretty sure that you could find a readily available implementation on the interwebz if you did a quick search)

Comment: I know i will have to implement my own solution, the problem is ...How will I start, should I save the Name as a string then compare the information of this and then look for the information of who's on top of the list and so on...

Comment: Read the info in the links posted. They both have pseudocode implementations - shouldn't be too tough to translate it to c

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort an array of structures, you can use the `qsort` function, see `man qsort`. It takes a base address of the array, number of elements, element size and comparing function:

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    Medico *medA = (Medico*) a;
    Medico *medB = (Medico*) b;
    return /* compare medA and medB */;
}

Medico *medicos = /* initialize */;
qsort(medicos, numberOfMedicos, sizeof(Medico), compare);
```

D’oh, just now I noticed the next-record pointer that probably makes this answer useless. (I’ve changed the question title to make the linked list apparent.) To make at least something from this answer, you can always copy the list into an array:

```
Medico *medicos = calloc(sizeof(Medico), numberOfMedicos);
Medico *current = /* first record in your linked list */;
int i = 0;

assert(current);
do {
    medicos[i++] = *current;
    current = current->next;
} while (current);

// Here you can sort the array.

free(medicos);
```

Of course, it depends on the number of records and other variables.

(My C is a bit rusty, feel free to fix.)

Comment: for a second there it seemed like a lifesaver, I need this before the next 4 hours... its 2.33 and its one of the last things I need... :/

Comment: Your second answer seems pretty neat, ill try it and tell you what I come up with; thanks